# Change dates on a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, lapply, lubridate

I have a list of dataframe with 8 variables in each of 6 dataframes. The 5th variable is a date and I would like to convert it from class character to a Date using lubridate. The date is in the form dd-mmm-yy. Currently I am using

```
firstOfMonth <- lapply(fileList,function(x) { x[5] <-
as.Date(strftime(x, format="%d-%b-y"))
```

})

but am getting the following error.

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz) :
```

do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”

Additionally, I would like to change the class of the 8th column to numeric. The following has not been successful.

```
lapply(listDF, function(df) mutate_at(df, vars(matches("^Amount")), as.numeric))

Name    Address City    District    Date    Visit   Completed   Amount
Baxter  1211 South Ave  Akron   A   4-Mar-22    Y   Y   12.02
Christ  105 Main Str    Akron   B   4-Mar-22    Y   N   0
Matthews    152 5th Str Akron   A   4-Mar-22    N   N   0
James   45 River Rd Akron   C   4-Mar-22    Y   Y   24.25
Lewis   92 Washington Str   Akron   D   4-Mar-22    Y   Y   16.5
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data from one of the data frames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format for `as.Date` should be

```
as.Date(x, format="%d-%b-%y") #note the `y` in the OP's code
```

In addition to that, there is only assignment of the 5th column to `Date` column, but it is not returning the `x` i.e. the `data.frame`

```
lapply(fileList,function(x) { 
      x[,5] <- as.Date(x[,5], format="%d-%b-%y");
   x})
```

---

This could be done more easily with `transform` (where we are changing multiple columns)

```
lapply(fileList, transform, Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d-%b-%y"),
       Amount = as.numeric(as.character(Amount))))
```

Also, it is not clear whether the 'Amount' is `factor` class or not.  If it is just `character` class, remove the `as.character`

---

With `tidyverse`, this can be done using `map` (from `purrr`) and `mutate` (from `dplyr`)

```
library(tidyverse)
map(fileList, ~ .x %>%
                  mutate(Date = dmy(Date),
                         Amount = as.numeric(as.character(Amount))))
```